# Please welcome your new moderators, AJ and Arnoud!

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm pleased to announce that two people that are very passionate about making this site work have stepped up and agreed to take on the roles and responsibilities of a moderator:

[image: profile for AJ Henderson at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]


[image: profile for Arnoud Traa at Sound Design Stack Exchange, Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts]

Arnoud has been with this community since the earlier days of Social Sound Design, and is coming on board to help ensure that Sound Design SE is the best place for Sound Designers to come get expert answers to their questions.

AJ was instrumental in the merge with our existing audio community, and has been basically working in the role of a moderator both on the main and meta sites. Both Arnoud and AJ have shown consistent fairness and level-headed thinking in their actions and interactions with other users.

They're joining the team today, as Andrew and Iain return to more 'ordinary citizens' of the site, however they've both promised that they'll be around and participate when they can.

Please give AJ and Arnoud a warm welcome and remember - we're all learning here as we take strides to make this a great place for both sound designers and audio production professionals and enthusiasts. Both have some fantastic ideas to help shape the focus of the site and attract questions that are more interesting to all participating, I'm very excited to see them join the team.

Comment: Congrats gentlemen!

Comment: Brilliant - 2 individuals who have really been putting in the effort to help define the scope of this site. Congratulations to you both!

Comment: Congrats and welcome!

Comment: way to step up guys.  best of luck.